# Selecting a div within the n'th element of an unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to click the div contained within the third item in the unordered list. So with the HTML (see at bottom) I am trying to click the div:

```
<li>
    <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
        <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/8/810b28b9-29e6-4e39-a104-510446431cdd/8756c0ae-84a2-464f-e15e-31bac0fc60ab-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Black Limelight" title="Giffin Design - Black Limelight">
    </div>
</li>
```

The jQuery selector to do this with I am trying as:

```
jQuery("#rg-ss-thumb-list :nth-child(3) > .rg-ss-thumb").click()
```

but I don't seem to be selecting the 3rd LI and consequently not the DIV as well. Could someone please point me in the right direction here?

```html
<ul class="rg-ss-thumb-list" style="width: 1356px;">
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/0/01c10df8-340e-4e15-bd6a-16e0eacd2edf/1c36b218-cae0-4f57-8b9b-74abb6a96850-thumb.jpg" alt="Cintemani Dan" title="Cintemani Dan">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/7/7b6ae878-30e0-443f-d5dc-510507b5cbbe/2507b8be-8b5e-473b-c06f-9fc9d3f26b8c-thumb.jpg" alt="Daniel Giffin Kurvi" title="Daniel Giffin Kurvi">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/8/810b28b9-29e6-4e39-a104-510446431cdd/8756c0ae-84a2-464f-e15e-31bac0fc60ab-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Black Limelight" title="Giffin Design - Black Limelight">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/a/a6800e34-10e9-4ac0-9937-9125172c668b/0c953b22-a69f-46cc-a934-e140fdc01511-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Black Limelight 2" title="Giffin Design - Black Limelight 2">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/9/9fd74ab2-4f23-4e10-af80-1dc13ce17b9d/39b63b87-d4f4-4a1a-be34-8a197307361a-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Copper" title="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Copper">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="rg-ss-thumb active">
         <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/5/5ff4fe7d-c462-4a9e-82ee-a65bba3d24e4/39d4f2dd-767e-4ea7-b4de-d3c29c6101a6-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Hawthorn" title="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Hawthorn">
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and

Comment: `#rg-ss-thumb-list` selects an element with that id, whereas yours has only a class set. (And what does this have to do with a form and “postback” as in the question title?)

Comment: Your use of `nth-child` needs to be revised as it's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your jQuery selector of `#rg-ss-thumb-list` is incorrect as you're trying to pull an `id`, while `rg-ss-thumb-list` is actually a `class`.

Secondly, your use of `nth-child` is incorrect. You need to use `nth-child` on the `list items`. This selector will work:

```
$(".rg-ss-thumb-list li:nth-child(3) .rg-ss-thumb");
```

To provide a quick working example:

```js
$(".rg-ss-thumb-list li:nth-child(3) .rg-ss-thumb").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rg-ss-thumb-list" style="width: 1356px;">
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/0/01c10df8-340e-4e15-bd6a-16e0eacd2edf/1c36b218-cae0-4f57-8b9b-74abb6a96850-thumb.jpg" alt="Cintemani Dan" title="Cintemani Dan"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/7/7b6ae878-30e0-443f-d5dc-510507b5cbbe/2507b8be-8b5e-473b-c06f-9fc9d3f26b8c-thumb.jpg" alt="Daniel Giffin Kurvi" title="Daniel Giffin Kurvi"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/8/810b28b9-29e6-4e39-a104-510446431cdd/8756c0ae-84a2-464f-e15e-31bac0fc60ab-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Black Limelight" title="Giffin Design - Black Limelight"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/a/a6800e34-10e9-4ac0-9937-9125172c668b/0c953b22-a69f-46cc-a934-e140fdc01511-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Black Limelight 2" title="Giffin Design - Black Limelight 2"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb ">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/9/9fd74ab2-4f23-4e10-af80-1dc13ce17b9d/39b63b87-d4f4-4a1a-be34-8a197307361a-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Copper" title="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Copper"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rg-ss-thumb active">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/media/rokgallery/5/5ff4fe7d-c462-4a9e-82ee-a65bba3d24e4/39d4f2dd-767e-4ea7-b4de-d3c29c6101a6-thumb.jpg" alt="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Hawthorn" title="Giffin Design - Cintemani - Hawthorn"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```